# Two Returns with no condition in Swift

Tags: swift

I have seen the following solution and I could not able to understand the use of return here.

How these two returns are separated from each other, where is the condition?

```
func majorityElement(_ nums: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var elems: [Int: Int] = [:]
    for n in nums {
        elems[n] = (elems[n] ?? 0) + 1
    }
    return elems.compactMap { key, value in 
        if value > nums.count / 3 { return key } 
        return nil 
    }
}
```

Comment: [_The Swift Programming Language_: Trailing Closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID102)

Comment: this can be reduced to `return nums.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1, default: 0] += 1 }.compactMap { $1 > nums.count / 3 ? $0 : nil }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the first return, `return elems.compactMap`, that returns the result of the `compactMap` as the function result (array) then there are two returns inside the closure that returns the result of the mapping i.e what gets added to the array.

If the given `value` is larger than `nums.count / 3` then `key` is returned and added to the array otherwise `nil` is returned meaning nothing gets added to the array.

Answer (score 2):

In order to understand that code you're going to have to read up on closures and higher-order functions.

A closure is an anonymous function - a block of code that doesn't have a name.

A higher-order function is a function that takes a closure as a parameter, and where the closure specifies what that function should do.

The Sequence function `sorted(by:)` is an example of a higher-order function. It takes a closure that takes two elements from the Sequence and returns `true` if the first item should appear first in the sorted output, or false otherwise.

`sorted()` is a general purpose function. The closure you pass it compares pairs of objects, and it does the rest.

`compactMap()` is another higher order function on various collections. In the code above it's performing compactMap on a `Dictionary`.

The code `return elems.compactMap{...}` takes the dictionary `elems` and passes each key/value pair in the dictionary into your closure. If your closure returns `nil` for a given key/entry pair that entry is dropped from the output.

The return you see inside the braces for the `compactMap` is a return for the closure. Again, compactMap calls your closure repeatedly, once for each key/value pair in the dictionary, and the closure has to return a value for each call.